# Leaflet.Draw сползли иконки после обновления

Tags: javascript, update, leafletjs

После обновления пакета Leaflet.Draw с версии 0.2.х до версии 0.4.9
на панели примитивов все иконки сползли.
Получается что шаг иконок какой то странный.

[image: btn.jpg]

здесь [есть решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337606/leaflet-edit-toolbar-icons-misaligned),но деталей нет, я так и не понял что надо сделать что бы решить данную проблему.

UPD. В одном из коментариев есть [ссылка](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/zolo/edit?html,output) на невозможность повторить проблему

но путем изменения строки `<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@0.4.1/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>`
на `<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@0.4.9/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>`, т.е. сменили версию Draw на последнюю, то получаем вот какой результат, но вот что делать если хочется использовать последнюю версию

[image: btn2.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось что проект использует так же пакет leaflet-illustrate из состава которого бралось изображение иконок toolbara, а там оно на 1 символ больше (300 х 30 пикс вместо положенных 270 х 30 пикс). В итоге для каждой иконки предоставлялось больше пикселей и они смещались, решилось заменой изображения spritesheet.png в пакете leaflet-illustrate аналогичным изображением из состава Leaflet.Draw.